# I want to get playlist view count with YouTube Data API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to get playlist view count with YouTube Data API. But I can't find a way from the YouTube DATA API reference. Please let me know if there is a way to get.

Answer (score -1):

The [Playlist endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) does not return a view count. You need to take those video IDs and make another call to the [Videos endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) to get them using part *statistics*.

Comment: The view that you will get making the call to video endpoint is the total views of the video which differs from playlist view.
For eg. You have 2 videos having 200 and 300 views. The two video added to a playlist and watched from there and got view 4 and 5 times so the playlist view will be 9 and not 500.

Comment: There is no separate view count for a video in a playlist. Downvote all you like.

Comment: The OP is asking for the playlist view and not the video view.

Comment: Again, there is no playlist view.

Comment: haha, see here.
https://imgur.com/gallery/Td6LEwP
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2FtXnB4g9pYWa-HyavYkwzRztJUg3q8i

Comment: Last time: it is not available through the API.

Comment: Now also it is not available through API. Only visible from UI. And the method you told is not the correct method to get it. By that method, you will get full video views which are different from the playlist view.